# Using Previous Record Function in Formula and then creating a Group Summary

Tags: function, crystal-reports, summary

I have been trying to figure this out and I am stumped. I am finding the difference in minutes between two times by using the following formula:

This formula is called {@CALCULATIONS}

```
if {Location.Name} = previous ({Location.Name}) then 
  ( hour({DownloadData.Date}) * 60 + minute({DownloadData.Date}) )-
  ( hour(previous({DownloadData.Date})) * 60 + minute(previous({DownloadData.Date})) ) 
else 
  0
```

I then uses the answer it comes up with in a formula that determines if it meets a criteria. If it does I assign it a 1 if not I assign it a zero. Here are the 5 different formulas I have for time ranges.

```
{@1 to 30} if {@Calculations} in 1 to 30 then 1 else 0
{@31 to 45} if {@Calculations} in 31 to 45 then 1 else 0
{@46 to 60} if {@Calculations} in 46 to 60 then 1 else 0
{@61 to 90} if {@Calculations} in 61 to 90 then 1 else 0
{@Morethan90} if {@Calculations} >90 then 1 else 0
```

For a while I have been trying to figure out how to get it to total the 1s that meet the formula criteria in the group.

Any suggestions?

Comment: where are you placing the {@Calculations} formula in design?

Comment: The {@Calculations} formula is the name I have for the top formula. I made the {@Calculations} formula so that if I need to adjust the formula I wouldnt have to adjust it in each of the other formulas that use it.

Comment: I should also note that I tried writing the {@calculations} formula into the {@1 to 30} formula and it still wasn't available for summary based on group. I have used this type of formula before and had success. The only thing that is different is that I am using the "previous" function in this instance where as the other instances I didnt have to.